# MSBuild Error 1 when building C++ proj with C# projs

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild

I am creating a build definition using Visual Studio 2012 and 2008 paired with Team Foundation Server 2012. I have to use Visual Studio 2008 for accessing older project files that cannot, for application purposes, be upgraded to Visual Studio 2012 project files. The build works fine (launched locally, built on build server) up until I add one last project file and attempt a build, the build fails and I am left with this error:

> Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException)
>   Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
>      at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>      at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

This is the only error report given, either in the build summary or log files.

Here is the interesting part, every project file builds fine when built individually on the build server, the error only appears when using the build definition.
My guess is that it has something to do with the fact that the contentious project file is a C++ project file (.vcproj), while all of the other files are C# proj files (.csproj). It is the only variable I can think of that would cause an error...

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this error? Or perhaps where to find a better description of the error?

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: 1. Is some kind of C++ SDK installed on the build server? 2. Have you checked the build.log file? Instead of searching for ": error" try to search for "-- failed".

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit more research I have a possible lead, but of course this lead has its own snags. It may have something to do with platform configurations, seeing as the C++ proj needs to be built using win32 platform config and the C# projs using AnyCPU. However in the configuration manager I do not have an option for win32 as a platform, and when attempting to create a new platform there isn't an option for win32 to copy settings from.

Does anyone know how to obtain the win32 platform config for use on VS2012 if it is completely absent?